# Everytime I am running Brownie run scripts/deploy.py, its showing the problem below, I need to understand what might be the problem with my install?

Tags: python, solidity, web3py, brownie

When I deploy this code, this is what happens?

```
brownie run scripts/deploy.py
Brownie v1.19.2 - Python development framework for Ethereum

BrownieSimpleStorageProject is the active project.

Launching 'ganache-cli --port 8545 --gasLimit 12000000 --accounts 10 --hardfork istanbul --mnemonic brownie'...
  File "brownie/_cli/run.py", line 51, in main
    return_value, frame = run(
  File "brownie/project/scripts.py", line 60, in run
    module = _import_from_path(script)
  File "brownie/project/scripts.py", line 156, in _import_from_path
    _import_cache[import_str] = importlib.import_module(import_str)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen, line line, in in
  File "<frozen, line line, in in
  File "<frozen, line line, in in
  File "<frozen, line line, in in
  File "<frozen, line line, in in
  File "<frozen, line line, in in
  File "<frozen, line line, in in
  File "<frozen, line line, in in
  File "<frozen, line line, in in
  File "<frozen, line line, in in
  File "<frozen, line line, in in
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mnt.c.users'
Terminating local RPC client...
```

I want to run my brownie in Ubuntu: brownie run scripts/deploy.py its keeps flagging that problem. Once installed, you will never have to activate a virtual environment prior to using Brownie.???

Answer (score 0):

The return value totally depends on what's inside your deployment script, which is scripts/deploy.py. Check the script and make everything right.

Comment: All I had to do was to make sure I brownie init in my linux, and code . to start it

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).